# Android : Design layout that contain empty field at bottom screen

Tags: android, layout

I want a layout, that the whole screen is `GridView` but at the "last line" (mean bottom of the screen) will be a textview or button (to display some status). I have design this layout like the code below :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".DishSelectionFragment" >

   <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView2"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:columnWidth="250dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </GridView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_price_dish"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:layout_marginTop="2px"
        android:textSize="20px" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have tried add text to textView, but when running in emulator, the text doesn't show. I don't know how to design layout satisfied my purpose. Please help me.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't see TextView as GridView takes whole space `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`
Just change GridView as follows:

```
<GridView
    [...]  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
/>
```

This will make your GridView fill all remaining space without pushing TextView out of visible area.

Answer (score 1):

In `GridView` change:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

or

```
android:layout_above="@+id/text_price_dish"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `RelativeLayout` as your parent layout and observe the added attributes. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    enter code heretools:context=".DishSelectionFragment">

   <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView2"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:columnWidth="250dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_above="@+id/text_price_dish" >   <!-- added -->
    </GridView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_price_dish"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:layout_marginTop="2px"
        android:textSize="20px"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >       <!-- added -->
    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```